# onPause(); for SwipeRefreshLayout not working

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, swiperefreshlayout, onpause

i have a ViewPager with 3 lists in view pager and every list have an simple SwipeRefreshLayout its working well but when RefreshLayout is reffreshing and you press the back button (onPause i think?) the program will crashed andthe error is you cant set null object i know the problem i dont know how to fix it
pls help this is my code

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment1,container,false);

    mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_news);
    refresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.refresh);
    refresh.setColorSchemeColors(
            R.color.material_green_200,
            R.color.material_green_400,
            R.color.material_green_600,
            R.color.material_green_800
    );
    refresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            String uri = "http://192.168.1.101/mySite/Flowers/flowers.json";
            JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(uri,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
                            ArrayList items = parser.parseJson(response);
                            FlowerAdapter adapter = new FlowerAdapter(getContext(),
                                    R.layout.activity_last_news_fragment,items);
                            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
            RequestQueue quew = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            quew.add(request);
            refresh.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });

   String uri = "http://192.168.1.101/mySite/Flowers/flowers.json";
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(uri,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
                    ArrayList items = parser.parseJson(response);
                    FlowerAdapter adapter = new FlowerAdapter(getContext(),
                            R.layout.activity_last_news_fragment,items);
                    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue quew = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    quew.add(request);
    return view;

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (refresh.isRefreshing()){
        refresh.setEnabled(false);
    }else {
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

how can i override onpause method to when it called first stop refreshing then pause?

and this is compelete error Log

```
12-07 17:11:41.942 13992-13992/app.mma.introsliderproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: app.mma.introsliderproject, PID: 13992
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at app.mma.PokerInfo.twitch.TwitchFragment$2.onResponse(TwitchFragment.java:73)
                                                                            at app.mma.PokerInfo.twitch.TwitchFragment$2.onResponse(TwitchFragment.java:67)
                                                                            at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
                                                                            at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Please share your complete logs.

Comment: there is anyway to ovveride the main activity onBackPressed could fix this?

Comment: Basically the problem is your getActivity() not with swiperefreshinglayout, try to put if(getActivity()!=null && !getActivity().isFinishing()) every where you have used getActivity() and context.

Comment: Are you using `FragmentActivity`?

Comment: no im using Fragment

Comment: How did you use `Fragment Transaction` ? I mean how did you put your `Fragment` on `Activity`? Share that code please.

Comment: my fragment is a simple list in viewPager and View Pager in the activity sorry if i cant understand im so new to android

Answer (score 1):

This is causing issue  `Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());` inside `onRefresh()`. You will need to check is your activity is in running state i.e is the context null or not.

```
@Override
    public void onRefresh () {
        if (YourFragment.this.isVisible()) {
            String uri = "http://192.168.1.101/mySite/Flowers/flowers.json";
            JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(uri,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
                        ArrayList items = parser.parseJson(response);
                        FlowerAdapter adapter = new FlowerAdapter(getContext(),
                                R.layout.activity_last_news_fragment,items);
                        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        RequestQueue quew = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        quew.add(request);
        refresh.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }
```

Put everything inside `if(){}` to avoid crash

Comment: can you please give me some details i cant understand

Comment: no but i find an other way to solve the problem please check my answer and thanks a lot for helping me

Comment: the conferim to exit is not working still crash can you please edit my code and give it to me im really cant undrestand

Comment: Process: app.mma.introsliderproject, PID: 8680
                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

Comment: if (getActivity()!=null && !getActivity().isFinishing()){
            RequestQueue quew = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            quew.add(request);
        }       notWorking eaither